ggplot2 Faceting with Multiple Variables
How can I create a faceted ggplot histogram with multiple grouping variables in R?
I have a dataset with columns: product, category, sales. I want to create a histogram of sales faceted by both product and category.
Here's a sample of my data:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  product = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  category = rep(c("X", "Y"), 15),
  sales = sample(100:200, 30, replace = TRUE)
)

Tried: facet_grid(product ~ category).
Expected: Separate histograms for each product-category combo.
Result: Incorrect facetting, histograms overlapped.

Please add all of your code.

The default plot as you've described looks ok to me, but maybe you're making it differently, or I'm not noticing the problem(s). Can you be more specific about your code and how the output varies from expectation?

This is what I think you are looking for:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
  product = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 10),
  category = rep(c("X", "Y"), 15),
  sales = sample(100:200, 30, replace = TRUE)
)

data

gg <- data |> 
  ggplot()+aes(x = sales,fill = product)+geom_histogram(position = "dodge")+
  facet_grid(c(~product,~category))

gg



You can slso use facet_wrap(~product+category)
